# VBA Code to Call API Returns XML instead of JSON

Tags: json, xml, vba

I am using an API. I have credentials. It returns XML instead of JSON.

```vb
Sub usbRequest()

    Dim objRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim strURL As String

    Set objRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    strURL = "https://someAPIURL.com/"

    objRequest.Open "GET", strURL, True, "MyUserName", "MyPassword"
    objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objRequest.send

    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Debug.Print objRequest.responseText

End Sub
```

The API Documentation indicates that an Accept header specifying JSON should return JSON.  I do have a reference set to Microsoft XML V 6.0.

Comment: Can't see how we can help further here. Carefully check documentation of API or reach out to vendor. They may be diverting JSON to XML on their end.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do that.